# Channel API: Presence URLs are not called when deployed to production module

Tags: google-app-engine, go, channel-api

I have a Go app using the Channel API that works fine locally, presence URLs are called and clients can send data back and forth to eachother via the channel API.

However, once deployed, presence URLs are *not* called- at least from what I see both in the app itself and in the logs on the Google console (i.e. no logs to /_ah/channel/*). Clients can still connect and send data back and forth to eachother (i.e. can force them to notify on connect via a faked presence call issued via ajax), but no presence

This only happens when I deploy as a module

Here is the app.yaml if that helps:

```
application: my-app-name
module: chat
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

inbound_services:
- channel_presence

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Comment: Please see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26622898/3852106). Judging by your app.yaml, you correctly enabled the service, but need to define presence path handlers. Hope it helps.

Comment: For the time being I've just ported it to using the main app instead of modules, but might play with explicitly naming the handlers instead of relying on "/.*" later. Thanks!